# Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am fairly new to this and trying to figure out the correct format to solve the error in the title. I get on the line: let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Pugs.m4a", ofType: nil)!

I know I must be missing something just not sure where.

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!

var playPug = 1

var player: AVAudioPlayer!

@IBAction func playPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Pugs.m4a", ofType: nil)!

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath)

    do  {

        if playPug == 1 {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            player = sound
            sound.play()
            playPug = 2
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause_Icon.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            player.pause()
            playPug = 1
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"play_Icon.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: If you look at Apple's documentation you will see that the method is `init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL)` and uses Swift 2 error handling. The documentation should always be your first place to look. Link to `AVAudioPlayer` documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:error: . Link to Swift Error Handling documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: Thanks, I see the init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL) method example. I am still not sure how to change it though. I have never seen "throw" before..

Comment: SO is not a good place for tutorials. I suggest you do an internet search for a tutorial on Swift error handling. Example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch

Comment: Thanks, helpful! I have updated the code and it works except for a fatal error i am trying to work out now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` is because of the `!` in this line of code:

```
let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Pugs.m4a", ofType: nil)!
```

It's crashing because you're using `!` to *force unwrap* the value returned by `pathForResource(_:ofType:)`, which is unsafe. If the value is `nil`, you get the `unexpectedly found nil` error. You should really only force unwrap things when you know they're not going to be `nil`.

---

Try doing something like this instead:

Option 1:

```
guard let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Pugs.m4a", ofType: nil) else {
    // The resource does not exist, so the path is nil.
    // Deal with the problem in here and then exit the method.
}

// The resource exists, so you can use the path.
```

---

Option 2:

Use optional binding, like this:

```
if let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Pugs.m4a", ofType: nil) {

    // The resource exists, and now you have the path, so you can use it.

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath)

    do {

        if playPug == 1 {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            player = sound
            sound.play()
            playPug = 2
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause_Icon.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            player.pause()
            playPug = 1
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"play_Icon.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

} else {
    // The path was nil, so deal with the problem here.
}
```